# Is it possible to split the SecurityConfig of spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, gradle

I have a project with `childA` and `childB`.

I want to configure the security of `childA` controllers in `childA` and `childB` controllers in `childB`.

So far I have the following `SecurityConfig`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    private CookieProperties cookieProperties;

    @Autowired
    private LdapUserDetailsManager userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;

    @Autowired
    private LogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private LdapProperties ldapProperties;

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;


    @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public LdapDaoAuthenticationProvider ldapDaoAuthenticationProvider(LdapProperties ldapProperties) {
        LdapDaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new LdapDaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        provider.setLdapProperties(ldapProperties);
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return provider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

            auth.authenticationProvider(ldapDaoAuthenticationProvider(ldapProperties));

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .requestMatcher(
                // how to move this in another file ?
                new OrRequestMatcher(
                    new AntPathRequestMatcher(ChildAHttpPathStore.PATH_SOMETHING),
                    new AntPathRequestMatcher(ChildBHttpPathStore.PATH_SOMETHING),
                )
            )
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)
                .and()
            .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(corsCookieCsrfTokenRepository())
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, CoreHttpPathStore.PING).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().hasAnyAuthority(
                        UserManagement.ROLE_AUTH_SERVICE
                )
            .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler)
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl(CoreHttpPathStore.LOGIN)
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler)
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl(CoreHttpPathStore.LOGOUT)
                .logoutSuccessUrl(CoreHttpPathStore.LOGIN_FROM_LOGOUT)
                .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .headers().cacheControl().disable();
    }

    @Bean(name = "userPasswordEncoder")
    public LdapShaPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new LdapShaPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public CookieSerializer cookieSerializer() {
        DefaultCookieSerializer serializer = new DefaultCookieSerializer();
        if (null != cookieProperties.getName()) { serializer.setCookieName(cookieProperties.getName()); }
        if (null != cookieProperties.getPath()) { serializer.setCookiePath(cookieProperties.getPath()); }
        if (null != cookieProperties.getHttpOnly()) { serializer.setUseHttpOnlyCookie(cookieProperties.getHttpOnly()); }
        if (null != cookieProperties.getMaxAge()) { serializer.setCookieMaxAge(cookieProperties.getMaxAge()); }
        if (null != cookieProperties.getSecure()) { serializer.setUseSecureCookie(cookieProperties.getSecure()); }
        if (null != cookieProperties.getDomain()) { serializer.setDomainName(cookieProperties.getDomain()); }
        return serializer;
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsCookieCsrfTokenRepository corsCookieCsrfTokenRepository(){
        CorsCookieCsrfTokenRepository repository = new CorsCookieCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setCookieHttpOnly(false);
        repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        repository.setCookiePath(cookieProperties.getPath());
        repository.setCookieDomain(cookieProperties.getDomain());
        repository.setCookieName("XSRF-TOKEN");
        return repository;
    }

}
```

Is it possible to split this configuration ?

Comment: you can separate and use @import to import where you need

Comment: Do I just write the configure method with `http.requestMatcher(/mypath)` and it will work? what about the chain after?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to write Multiple HttpSecurity due to [spring security docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity) the easiest is to create a general configuration with some internal **@Configuration** classes for configuring HttpSecurity

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MultiHttpSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() throws Exception {
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        manager.createUser(User.withUsername("user").password("password").roles("USER").build());
        manager.createUser(User.withUsername("admin").password("password").roles("USER","ADMIN").build());
        return manager;
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)                                                        
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/api/**")                               
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .and()
                .httpBasic();
        }
    }

    @Configuration                                                  
    public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using two different project, so this class needs to be in two different files

Comment: are you looking something like this http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-entry-points

Comment: this is way too complicated. I just want to be able to declare matches in each respective package and not store all my matches (configured with antMatcher) in one file.